# Oracle:SQL Plus finding Top/bBttom 25% percentile

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, sqlplus

I have a table

```
SUM_Q1     SUM_Q2     SUM_Q3     SUM_Q4
```

---

```
     4          4          4          4
     5          5          5          5
```

etc

and i was wondering how i can take the top and bottom %25 percentile values for each column. 
I am using this with jdbc and java to print out the statistics of the table but I do not know the way to do this or begin.

I originally tried the following:`SELECT survey_id,sum_q1, PERCENTILE_DISC(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY survey_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cid) "Percentile_DISC" FROM Surveys;` 
but found out that it will only give me the median for the top 25..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably several ways to do this, but this came to my mind first (if I understand correctly what you want):

```
with d as (
  select 1 as val1, 2 as val2 from dual
  union all
  select 2 as val1, 3 as val2 from dual
  union all
  select 4 as val1, 5 as val2 from dual
  union all
  select 6 as val1, 7 as val2 from dual
  union all
  select 8 as val1, 9 as val2 from dual
  union all
  select 10 as val1, 11 as val2 from dual
  union all
  select 12 as val1, 13 as val2 from dual
   union all
  select 14 as val1, 15 as val2 from dual
)
select val1 from (
  select val1, ntile(4) over (order by val1 asc) bucket_val1
  from d
)
-- depending or ordering (asc or desc), bucket 1 or 4 will be top or bottom 25%
where bucket_val1 = 4
```

Output:

```
VAL1
12
14
```

The above example just looks at one column (val1).  The top or bottom 25% values would depend on your ordering.  More on [ntile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions115.htm#SQLRF00680)